# Bind multiple properties in subscribe method from observable data in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

How would I set multiple variables once I subscribe to an observable?

In other terms: I Want to set multiple component properties within the subscription of an observable, based on the returned data. Such as:

```
data => { this.p1=data.p1; this.p2=data.p2;}
```

I have tried so many approaches but only the entire data is binding with one property. But I want to get internal data in subscription method itself.

Any suggestion really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are inside of a subscription, you have access to your class variables and can deconstruct the data received from the subscription any way you want.

```
let myObservable = [however I define or get my observable]

myObservable.subscribe((data: any) => {

    this.p1 = data.p1;
    this.p2 = data.p2;
    // any other code you want to execute when observable fires
});
```

This is, of course, assuming that `data.p1` and `data.p2` actually exist.  You might get an error in the case that `data` is `null` or `undefined` if `data.p1` or `data.p2` do not exist.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question that I have already tried this but data.p2 is undefined. but If I directly pass the whole data into DOM and try to get P2 then it is fine. 

But I have to get it on component itselft... Any idea?

Comment: In order to understand this better, in your subscribe method can you do a `console.log("data : "  + JSON.stringify(data));` and post the result of this?

Comment: I can not do this, because of my data has a type and once I use JSON.stringify(data), it will convert into string.

Comment: @MukeshKumar I understand, but it will allow us to see the contents of the data - which is crucial in this case to debug - at least from a distance.